# how to cancel led notification , when screen is unlocked in android?

Tags: android, notifications, led

i have an app that when airplane mode is on , led light notification start . i want to stop or cancel this led light , when my screen is unlocked.how can i handle this?

i try this but not worked:

```
....
 PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
    if (isScreenOn) {
        stop();
    }
}


public void stop(){
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        }


}
```

if i want to cancel this led light , when airplane mode is off, how can i check this event?

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, handle the (ACTION_USER_PRESENT) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT -- this is when the device is unlocked. Then do the cancellation.

```
<receiver android:name=".Receive">
    <intent-filter android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver {
    if (intent.getAction() != null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE != null) {
                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
                nMgr.cancel(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code, so you may need to modify it. But hopefully the concept is right.

Answer (score 1):

Where's your code?

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
    if (isScreenOn) {
        stop();
    }
```

I believe there's nothing wrong here, but if you're declaring it on `onCreate()` it won't work.

You need to register a receiver.

```
registerReceiver(this.screenOffListener, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"));
```

And declare your code in the right place

```
public class ScreenOffListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public ScreenOffListener() {}

    public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
    {
        // place your code
    }
}
```